Formio Odoo: State not changing to "completed" after submission
Subject: Formio ODOO.
The issue is the state is not changing to "complete" after clicking submit button and the data submitted is not being saved in the form either. I can see the green notification on top of the form saying "Completed" when clicking submit button but the state remains "Pending"
I tried to change some options in the form builder but the issue still.

Do you have any debugging info that you can share (like F12-network-protocol, backend logs etc)?
